# PL/SQL WEBSERVICE - https connection to

Tags: web-services, plsql

I would like to connect to a webservice for the help of PL / SQL to the site based on the https protocol. Do you have any ideas what package you use the UTL_DBWS or UTL_HTTP

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a complex web service, I'd prefer to use UTL_HTTP as per this tutorial: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/utl_http-and-ssl.php

Comment: I'm going to build function or proceure PL/SQL that will connect to the WebService and it will send the data to the webservice want to let it connect to https

Comment: Yep - have a look at the link, it should show you how to use UTL_HTTP to connect to the WS via https.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have one question what is the orapki and how it can be installed in version 11g. As soon as the song the certificate to a local drive it I get an error: "Unable to open file"

Comment: I haven't used it myself. Info on orapki was linked at the bottom of the article - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10746/asoappf.htm